# Replace the default arrow that comes with the datalist

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

I have used a datalist here. I want to change the default arrow that comes with the datalist. Is there any way I can get the arrow shown in the second image, instead of the default arrow ?
Thank you.

[image: default arrow]

[image: the arrow I need]

```css
.contact-input-datalist::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}

.contact-input-datalist {
  position: relative;
  background-color: ;
}

.contact-input-datalist:before {
  content: "\f073";
  display: inline-block;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" list="events" class="uk-input contact-input-datalist" placeholder="Type of Event" />
  <datalist name="" id="events">
        <option>Event 1</option>
        <option>Event 2</option>
        <option>Event 3</option>
        <option>Event 4</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Use your first class to hide the default arrow. Then use the image for the `:before`.

Comment: @Azu Thanks for the reply. Did you mean to use the image as a background? I tried it and didn't work. If you have another way to do this please mention it.

Answer (score 1):

`input` and `datalist` don't support `:before`, so the background arrow is placed into the `input`. You need to mind the path of the arrow image.

```css
.contact-input-datalist::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity:0;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background:#fff url(arrow.png) 145px -20px no-repeat;
    padding-right: 35px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" list="events" class="uk-input contact-input-datalist"  placeholder="Type of Event" />
    <datalist name="" id="events">
        <option>Event 1</option>
        <option>Event 2</option>
        <option>Event 3</option>
        <option>Event 4</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```